# Adding a project to java build path from terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

If I have two projects say projectA and projectB both in different packages, the moment I add projectB to the Java Build Path from eclipse, it is allowing me to import projectB in projectA. Now is there any way I can achieve the same thing from the terminal? As far as I have searched, I did not get a proper answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set the classpath, see this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build both projects and [package them as JAR files](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Tutorial%3A+Build+a+JAR+file+with+Maven+in+5+minutes). Then on the command line you [include both JAR files on your classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/including-all-the-jars-in-a-directory-within-the-java-classpath)

For example place your JAR files in a sub-directory named `lib` then you can execute your application like so

```
java -cp ".;lib/*" my.package.MainClass
```

In this example I have used the Windows path separator `;` inside the quotes used to define the classpath. The dot `.` denotes the current working directory which you may or may not need. The class `my.package.MainClass` is expected to exist in either the current working directory, or in any *.jar file in the `lib` directory.

Comment: This is probably the best way, but it should also be said that adding the directory which contains the compiled classes to the classpath also works.

Comment: @Brad,as per your link, the tutorial asks for a pom.xml file which i do not have. I created a Java project from eclipse and the project and its java file is stored in the workspace itself.

Comment: If you are not using a Maven project in Eclipse you can always use `File > Export > Jar File` for each project and then you have your JAR files. If you are learning Java I highly recommend you also learn a build tool like Maven. You can start with creating a Maven project in Eclipse and it creates everything you need for you including the pom.xml

Comment: thanks for your comment now i build both the projects and all jars are placed under a common folder. Now in terminal, from which location should I execute the above given command?

Comment: Thanks for guiding me like a baby.. You were really awesome and the answer worked like a king!! Thanks a ton once again..